# Limit what fields can be edited GeoExplorer OpenGeoSuite

Tags: editing, boundless-suite, security, geoexplorer, user-account

I have an issue with limiting what fields can be edited by the user. If I link my layer to my PostGIS table, the user is able to edit all the fields for a specific point.

If I create a view I can limit what they can see, however views are read only?

Any obvious solutions I am not thinking about to allow me to limit which fields they can change or fill in when modifying a layer?

Using OpenGeo Suite, GeoExplorer.

Comment: Would it have to be a new table and foreign keys to link the data the user enters in the map, to a new table which is then linked to my existing table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you editing a certain layer, or do you need it to work with multiple layers? In the first case you should be able to limit the fields in the FeatureEditor plugin by using the fields config option:

http://gxp.opengeo.org/master/doc/lib/plugins/FeatureEditor.html

Alternatively, you can override the schema in GeoServer I believe:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wfs/schemamapping.html

GeoExplorer will use this (the output to WFS DescribeFeatureType) to determine which fields to show.